# KISS way to copy a list of tables between SQL instances?

Tags: sql-server, architecture, ssis, etl

My main application has nightly SSIS jobs that move some (not all) of the data from the production servers to various test and development servers.

These jobs do nothing fancy.  They delete the destination table and repopulate it from the source.  There are many dozens of tables and 4 or 5 servers in the mix, with plenty of foreign keys, but everything is SQL to SQL and there is no merging or lookups.

Using SSIS to do this has proven painfully brittle.  When a new application release changes the schema, more than half the time, jobs begin failing.  Why? The updates are done by the developers, and the packages have been tweaked and changed dozens of times by different developers and often the SSIS changes happen during crunch time of the development cycle.

It has occurred to me that SSIS may or may not be the right tool for this.  SSIS is  pretty bloated for simple table copies.  (Column Mapping, etc.)  Is there a better way?  Ideally, it would simply take as input (preferably from a central source):

- an unordered list of tables (Nothing but exact match column naming supported)
- a source server
- a destination server

It would then simply:
 - Begin execution on a schedule at the designated server.
 - sort the list referentially (to not violate FK constraints)
 - delete/truncate all the destination tables in referential order
 - Copy tables from source to destination in referential order
 - Report back success or failure.

The only challenging things on the list (I think) would be a good low-maintenance way to schedule the jobs and for the jobs to report back success or failure.

[Note:  I'm not looking for technical details.  I am simply looking for a lower maintenance, less brittle way to make these data moves happen.  I'll post my initial idea below as a possible solution, but I'll be quite happy if there is a simpler solution out there.]

Comment: My initial thought would be to have a single SSIS package do an Execute SQL task that sends service broker messages to the servers doing the actual copying.  Each server would have a service broker queue with an activation SP that takes the lists, generates a SQL script for the copy and then executes it and sends success/failure/info messages back via service broker.  The SSIS package that kicked things off would wait for each job to complete (or timeout) and log to the SSIS history log.   Quite possible there is an even simpler way.

Comment: Why not just use replication to move this data from Production to Test?

Comment: Are FKs in the destination table required, or are you basically just backing up data or caching to another server?  How about indexes?  Because dropping and copying tables over is pretty easy if you can ignore those things.  Less easy if you need to replicate FKs & indexes and such.

Comment: I have never seen a copy from prod back to lower environments go well and I have seen several whole-hearted attempts.  The problem is that schemas change first in lower environments and then eventually roll out to prod.  But you are usually in a constant state of differences between them.  Even if you get past the schema differences, lower environments have different data, as they should for effective, repeatable tests.  I would just advice you to consider what benefit you are really getting out of it and consider whether your tests are designed well or are they also brittle.

Comment: Have you considered BIML? http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2015/01/biml-replicate-o-matic.html It will update with the latest version of the tables when you regenerate the packages and you don't have to do the manual column mapping.

Comment: @mmarie You need to post that as an answer.  That looks like a brilliant solution for what I need, and I'd like to give you credit

Answer (score 0):

Instead of truncating tables and copying data, you could DROP the tables, and use the Transfer SQL Server Objects Task to copy the table, which would include DDL changes.

Caveat being that you would have to handle foreign keys accordingly.